# Padre under ActivePerl: not working?

Tags: perl, activeperl, padre

I have ActivePerl version 5.12.2.1202 and PPM version 4.11 installed.

I would like to use a debugger with a GUI where I can see the Perl program variables. After getting disappointed of Eclipse and EPIC, (since it seems they are terribly un-userfriendly and unforgiving (lots of failures)), I decided to try out Padre.

I added the wxperl repository to the PPM repositories, and downloaded Padre.

When I go "padre" at the command prompt, I get the error:

> The program can't start because wxmsw28u_core_custom.dll is missing
>   from your computer.

I then uninstalled Padre, and followed the advice on the ActivePerl web site - at the command prompt, I say: "ppm install padre". Padre gets installed, but again, when I go "padre" at the command prompt, I get the error:

> The program can't start because wxmsw28u_core_custom.dll is missing
>   from your computer.

(Note that Padre is supposed to be working with ActivePerl).

My system is Windows 7 x64. I have run the command box as "administrator", and it didn't help.

What to do?

Comment: Working with Strawberry Perl I found that it's preferable to install the x86 version instead of the x86_64 one.

Comment: I've seen similar message with older ppms, but using AS perl 5.12.4 and [www.wxperl.co.uk](http://www.wxperl.co.uk) ppm repo works well for me these days. However I am using XP 32bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can just try [Dwim Perl](http://dwimperl.com/) which already contains Padre 0.94. I also sent a message to Mark, the owner of wxperl.co.uk to upgrade Padre to 0.94. That guy is just awesome. Support for padre is usually found at [#padre](http://padre.perlide.org/support.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it this way: I uninstalled wx- related packages which originated from the ActiveState repository, and installed the packages with the same name originating from the wxPerl repository.

I learned it here:

https://groups.google.com/group/binary-wxperl/browse_thread/thread/f53be0143430f408?hl=en#

(see the answer, second post)